# Order vertices by degree in CircularEmbedding for graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to draw a graph in circular layout but I would like to position the vertices in descending order on the circle. Can this be done in an easy way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort the vertices first. Here is an example graph:

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomGraph[{20,40}]
```

[image]

We can use [`DegreeCentrality`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DegreeCentrality) to get all of the degrees:

```
DegreeCentrality[g]
```

> {5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7}

So, the following should do what you want:

```
Graph[
    VertexList[g][[Ordering[DegreeCentrality[g]]]],
    EdgeList[g],
    GraphLayout->"CircularEmbedding"
]
```

[image]

Comment: Any reason you chose `DegreeCentrality` over `VertexDegree`?

Answer (score 4):

#### GraphPropertyChart

`` GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart `` is an alternative way to visualize vertex degree centralities using a circular layout.

Using Carl Wolls' example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
g = RandomGraph[{20, 40}]; 
dc = DegreeCentrality[g];
ordering = Ordering[dc];

GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[g, Automatic -> dc[[ordering]],
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{dc[[ordering]], ordering}, {"RadialCenter", "RadialCallout"}]},
  ChartStyle -> "SolarColors"] /. False -> True
```

[image]

Or, remove the annuli and disks from the callout lines:

```
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[g, Automatic -> dc[[ordering]],
 ChartElementFunction -> None,
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{dc[[ordering]], ordering}, {"RadialCenter", "RadialCallout"}]},
 ChartStyle -> "SolarColors"] /. False -> True /. _Disk:> {}
```

[image]

To order vertices by a property other than the default `DegreeCentrality`, say `BetweennessCentrality`, we use the desired ordering as the value of the option `Automatic`:

```
bc = BetweennessCentrality[g]; 
GraphComputation`GraphPropertyChart[g,
    Automatic -> Sort[bc], 
    ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
    ChartLabels -> {Placed[{Sort@bc, Ordering@bc}, 
      {"RadialCenter", "RadialCallout"}]}]  /. _Disk :> {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you already have some graph properties (such as edge or vertex weights) or some graph styling.  The `IGReorderVertices` convenience function from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) makes it easy to preserve these properties during reordering.

Here's a styled graph:

```
g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[20, 3], VertexSize -> Large, EdgeStyle -> Gray] // 
  IGVertexMap[ColorData["SolarColors"], VertexStyle -> Rescale@*VertexDegree]
```

[image]

And here it is with circular layout:

```
IGReorderVertices[
  VertexList[g][[ Ordering@VertexDegree[g] ]], 
  Graph[g, GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding"]
]
```

[image]